# Retention of field history data

Tags: history-tracking

Do you know if there is a limit to the amount of data stored when tracking field history?

I know there are a limit of 20 fields per object, but in the limits table, I can't find anything about the actions to log for each fieldhttps://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US

so, do you know if there is any limit? or is something like, the log can be considered a file and enters into the file limits or something?

Comment: Do you mean the number of actual logged changes per record, in other words defining a data retention policy for field history?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean: how many changes can be logged or how many time will be in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "actions" can mean several things at the moment in the Force.com platform, but I'll take this question to be focused on the retention of actual logged changes made for a given record.

Currently the retention policy for field history is permanent. But this is likely to change in the future.

The first attempt at controlling retention of field history took place about a year ago, where field history was intended to be kept for 18 months. This blanket policy proved too inflexible for many salesforce.com customers, and so the move to implement this was reversed until a more flexible process could be defined.

In Winter 14 a pilot program to allow customers to define specific retention policy for field history changes was begun and is continuing today as per the release notes of Summer 14.

In the Summer 14 release notes the following is stated about this pilot program:

> As the first part of a larger data life cycle management initiative, salesforce.com is continuing the pilot that began in Winter '14. Use the Salesforce Metadata API to define a retention policy for your field history. Then use the REST API, SOAP API, and Tooling API to work with your archived data.

There is also a link provided for the [pilot implementation guide](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/field_history_retention.pdf) for any customers who would like to learn more about the pilot.

Comment: Spring 15 now has the feature available. Quoting Jonathan Bruce from  "https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kkDeAAI": "We are releasing support for the improved field history management as part of a platform add-on with #Field Audit Trails.  Available in #Spring'15, you will be able to track up to 60 fields/object and define a retention policy on a per object basis for up to 10 years."