# I am see records before 18 months without field audit trail in salesforce?

Tags: fields, history-tracking, field-history

I am a little confused with salesforce documentation here:

https://a.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/www/ocms/assets/pdf/misc/Platform_FieldAuditTrail_Datasheet.pdf.
As per the link, standard Field History tracking, allows for only 20 fields to be tracked for a period of 18 months. In my org, we have NOT enabled the 'Field Audit trail', still I'm able to see history records that are from early March, 2018.

Is there a way to check retention policy if any? I have tried to retrieve a standard object via metadata api, but unable to find any 'historyRetentionPolicy' tags within the extract. Does this get enabled only after enabling 'Field Audit trail'?

I'm worried that one fine day, I won't find any history records at all.

Is raising a case with Salesforce the only solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: @mavasv, Are you able to see the history in SobjectHistory object?

Comment: What object/fields are you referring to? Some standard ones are tracked - Opportunity Stage for example.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/tracking_field_history.htm): `If your org was created before June 1, 2011, Salesforce continues to retain all field history.`. But how much of the historical data would be maintained could be a grey area. So, you might want to check when your org was created. Few similar questions: [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187130/field-history-tracking-data-retention) & [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46379/retention-of-field-history-data).

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala , Yup i'm able to see the records in sObjectHistory

Comment: @Girbot , I'm able to see both standard as well as custom field history

Comment: @arut , good catch, let me check the org creation date, will review the other queries as well. Thanks

Comment: @MavsavSauve.  did you check if the org is created before JUNE 1 2011

Comment: Hello All, I just now checked, my Org is created in 12/2017. So definitely not before 2011.

Comment: I think a screenshot would helpful here, be mindful to hide any sensitive details. Would at least rule out a custom tracking solution.